# ContractFunctionExecutionError: The contract function "createCommitment" returned no data ("0x")

Tags: ethers.js, walletconnect, wagmi, wagmi-hooks, wagmi-react

I am using WalletConnect's Web3Modal together with Wagmi.
I am trying to use the hook provided by Wagmi -- `usePrepareContractWrite` and `useContractWrite`. Here is their [documentation](https://wagmi.sh/react/hooks/useContractWrite)

I applied the code in my Component.tsx and got the error, `ContractFunctionExecutionError: The contract function "createCommitment" returned no data ("0x").`

The error states that:

```
This could be due to any of the following:
  - The contract does not have the function "createCommitment",
  - The parameters passed to the contract function may be invalid, or
  - The address is not a contract.

Contract Call:
  address:   0xE435FB5dA9F14F36239c04E267c4f87Bd770D567
  function:  createCommitment(address[] _members, uint256 _premium, uint256 _frequency, uint256 _duration)
  args:                      (["0x5B38Da6a701c568545dCfcB03FcB875f56beddC4","0xAb8483F64d9C6d1EcF9b849Ae677dD3315835cb2","0x4B20993Bc481177ec7E8f571ceCaE8A9e22C02db"], 500, 120, 480)
  sender:    0xb617f96EcA626ff094169ac160452C082aF23284
```

None of the above is true.

There is no issue with the abi, argument types nor chain.

See [here](https://github.com/0xNike/Safe-Protocol/blob/main/Component.tsx) for my Component.tsx.

Comment: Did you find any solution to this? I have the same problem even with a basic `useReadContract` ?